# Query for command prompt in Aspen SQLPlus

Tags: aspen

How do you access the command prompt using Aspen SQLPlus? 
I have tried using `Host Dir`, but does not seem to work.

Comment: The [tag:sqlplus] tag is specifically for Oracle's SQL\*Plus client, which does have a `host` command, but this isn't the same thing. You might need to ask [on AspenTech's support pages](http://support.aspentech.com) to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **SYSTEM** command. This is covered quite well within the Aspen SQLPlus help menu.

E.g.

```
SYSTEM ('DIR'); 
SYSTEM ('DIR C:\WINDOWS\'); 
SYSTEM ('ROBOCOPY C:\SCRATCH\ C:\USERS\JOHN\DESKTOP\ TEST.TXT');
SYSTEM ('HOSTNAME');
SYSTEM ('WHOAMI');
```

Will print the results to screen.

Alternatively, you can format the results as a table:

```
select line, linenum from SYSTEM ('DIR');
```

It is also possible to interact with the results, within a for loop:

```
for (select linenum ilinenum, line iline from SYSTEM ('DIR'))
do
   write ilinenum || chr(9) || iline;
end
```

A few things to note:

- No interaction is possible, e.g. if you attempt to COPY a file and are prompted if you want to overwrite Y/N, this will get stuck.
- The IP21 Service Account will always execute the command, regardless of the user who executes the SQLPlus query.
- If you wish to execute multiple commands, you will need to load a batch file